# How to dis-ambiguate operator definitions between objects/classes in a programming language?

Tags: overloading, operator-keyword

I'm designing my own programming language (called Lima, if you care its on www.btetrud.com), and I'm trying to wrap my head around how to implement operator overloading. I'm deciding to bind operators on specific objects (its a prototype based language). (Its also a dynamic language, where 'var' is like 'var' in javascript - a variable that can hold any type of value).

For example, this would be an object with a redefined + operator:

```
x = 
{  int member

   operator + 
    self int[b]:
       ret b+self
    int[a] self:
       ret member+a
}
```

I hope its fairly obvious what that does. The operator is defined when x is both the right and left operand (using `self` to denote this).

The problem is what to do when you have two objects that define an operator in an open-ended way like this. For example, what do you do in this scenario:

```
A = 
{ int x
  operator +
   self var[b]:
    ret x+b
}

B = 
{ int x
  operator +
   var[a] self:
    ret x+a
}

a+b   ;; is a's or b's + operator used?
```

So an easy answer to this question is "well duh, don't make ambiguous definitions", but its not that simple. What if you include a module that has an A type of object, and then defined a B type of object.

How do you create a language that guards against other objects hijacking what you want to do with your operators?

C++ has operator overloading defined as "members" of classes. How does C++ deal with ambiguity like this?

Comment: Also, if you have a `var` keyword, I hope you are not making the same mistake as JavaScript and making variables global by default unless declared `var`. This leads to so many bugs (any variable where you forget to use `var` is automatically shared with all other variables in the program by the same name).

Comment: You gotta declare it, if not its an error. So not making the same mistake ; )

Comment: I'm not quite clear what your real goals are with the language.  You suggest that you're interested in performance, but it also sounds like you're duck-typing, which is generally works against performance.  I like the chaining of `a < b < c`, but at a quick glance I didn't notice how you handle arithmetic operations whose result could be larger than the operand types.

Comment: @supercat The goal is to be the best of both worlds. Maximize development productivity primarily, and use user-created optimization modules to maximize performance in an entirely automated way. The programmer has the power to define expected inputs to the program (command-line, network calls, etc) that give optimizers the info they need to work well. As far as arithmetic operations, values in lima actually don't have "types", and there is no upper bound on number sizes (other than typical memory constraints).

Comment: Feel free to leave a comment at the bottom of the documentation: http://www.btetrud.com/Lima/Lima-Documentation.html instead of on SO

Comment: @BT: A chat room might be more helpful if you want to create one and post a link.  Some issues to start off with: what would you expect the value of `1.0/3.0` to be?  How about `2.0^0.5`?  How would `2^(2^0.5) < 10^0.427572070255` be evaluated?  You seem to favor arbitrary-precision decimal floating point.  Do you know why programming languages don't?

Comment: Created one: http://us21.chatzy.com/55855297782806 . I do know why programming langauges *usually* don't. 1.0/3.0 is identical to 1/3 and is conceptually left unevaluated until the final destination of that data is known. If you're printing it to the screen with 2 decimal precision (and that's the only way you're using it), Lima might decide to use a single-precision float to store the value before printing. Same with the rest. If arbitrary-precision is needed, it can go as far as calculating these values symbolically (like mathematica does).

Comment: @BT: You didn't ping me, so I only just now noticed the chat room.

Comment: @BT: BTW, SO has its own built-in chat facility.

Comment: @supercat Hm, didn't know that: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/57376/lima

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most languages will give precedence to the class on the left. C++, I believe, doesn't let you overload operators on the right-hand side at all. When you define `operator+`, you are defining addition for when this type is on the left, for anything on the right.

In fact, it would not make sense if you allowed your `operator +` to work for when the type is on the right-hand side. It works for +, but consider -. If type A defines `operator -` in a certain way, and I do int x - A y, I don't want A's `operator -` to be called, because it will compute the subtraction in reverse!

In Python, which has more extensive [operator overloading rules](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames), there is a separate method for the reverse direction. For example, there is a `__sub__` method which overloads the - operator when this type is on the left, and a `__rsub__` which overloads the - operator when this type is on the right. This is similar to the capability, in your language, to allow the "self" to appear on the left or on the right, but it introduces ambiguity.

Python gives precedence to the thing on the left -- this works better in a dynamic language. If Python encounters `x - y`, it first calls `x.__sub__(y)` to see if `x` knows how to subtract `y`. This can either produce a result, or return a special value `NotImplemented`. If Python finds that `NotImplemented` was returned, it then tries the other way. It calls `y.__rsub__(x)`, which would have been programmed knowing that `y` was on the right hand side. If that also returns `NotImplemented`, then a `TypeError` is raised, because the types were incompatible for that operation.

I think this is the ideal operator overloading strategy for dynamic languages.

**Edit:** To give a bit of a summary, you have an ambiguous situation, so you really only three choices:

- Give precedence to one side or the other (usually the one on the left). This prevents a class with a right-side overload from hijacking a class with a left-side overload, but not the other way around. (This works best in dynamic languages, as the methods can decide whether they can handle it, and dynamically defer to the other one.)
- Make it an error (as @dave is suggesting in his answer). If there is ever more than one viable choice, it is a compiler error. (This works best in static languages, where you can catch this thing in advance.)
- Only allow the left-most class to define operator overloads, as in C++. (Then your class B would be illegal.)

The only other option is to introduce a complex system of precedence to the operator overloads, but then you said you want to reduce the cognitive overhead.

Comment: Interesting, but the problem here is that while being logically disambiguated, it still increases cognitive load. I'm trying to reduce cognitive load as much as possible. But +1!

Comment: I see ... I just realised now how your code works: The operator + in A is when A is on the left. The operator + in B is when B is on the right. So effectively you do have a flexible version of Python's __add__ and __radd__. I'll add a bit more to my answer.

Comment: @B T Note that if you added Python's NotImplemented thing, you could effectively create classes with precedence, as Python does. For example, say you have an Int class and a Float class, and you want Float addition to take precedence no matter which side Float is on. Well you could have both Int and Float overload + on both the left and right sides, but have Int return NotImplemented unless it encounters an Int. Therefore, it would dynamically defer to Float if either side was a Float.

Comment: So Lima actually has optional strong typing, so it doesn't need the NotImplemented thing to do what you're saying, it would just be something like: operator+[self int[b]: ret #x+b].

Comment: As far as your edit, I like option 2, but I'm worried that any error on ambiguities would require a whole system to be rewritten (3rd party modules and all). Thats not a situation I want to be in. Option 3 means operators pretty much have to be commutative - which is a limitation I don't like. 1 is ok, but it would be nice to somehow avoid ambiguities altogether if its possible to create a reasonable system that way.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with erroring on ambiguity because the damage is contained to just those two objects (and their ancestors) - which is ok with me. Thanks for helping me think through this!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer this question by saying "duh, don't make ambiguous definitions".

If I recreate your example in C++ (using a function `f` instead of the + operator and `int`/`float` instead of `A`/`B`, but there really isn't much difference)...

```
template<class t>
void f(int a, t b)
{
    std::cout << "me! me! me!";
}

template<class t>
void f(t a, float b)
{
    std::cout << "no, me!";
}

int main(void)
{
    f(1, 1.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

...the compiler will tell me precisely that: `error C2668: 'f' : ambiguous call to overloaded function`

If you create a language powerful enough, it's always going to be possible to create things in it that don't make sense. When this happens, it's probably ok to just throw up your hands and say "this doesn't make sense".

Comment: I agree with this. But I think it makes more sense for a static language. In a dynamic language, ambiguity errors usually seem weird at runtime. It's more usual for defaults to happen (such as defaulting to the left side overload).

Comment: So originally I think I hadn't fully grasped all the possibilities. But now I think I do. You either have a situation where someone else defined an object A, and you define an object B that operates with object A, or you define both objects. 

In both cases I think its perfectly reasonable to require that ambiguity not be coded. I think i'm actually going to go with "don't make ambiguous definitions" +1 (only not giving you the answer because mgiuca helped out so much. And because his answer gives all the options I have - including your option)

Answer (score 1):

In C++, a op b means a.op(b), so it's unambigious; the order settles it. If, in C++, you want to define an operator whose left operand is a built-in type, then the operator has to be a global function with two arguments, not a member; again, though, the order of the operands determines which method to call. It is illegal to define an operator where both operands are of built-in types.

Comment: I can't tell what you're saying here, exactly. I don't see where I said anything that precludes copy constructors from being members; indeed, I took for granted what the OP said, that most operators are member functions. No, class types are not built-in types, by definition. The rule is that at least one operand of any user-defined operator must be a user-defined type. In any event, if you'd like to tell me *what* statements I made are wrong, I'm all ears.

Comment: @Mahesh He isn't wrong, he just focussed on built-in types. The first sentence covers class types. There are two ways to do operator overloading in C++. You can either make it a method of the class on the left-hand side, or make it a global function which is overloaded to specify the type of both arguments. He is saying that built-in types can only be overloaded with the latter approach (since they don't have classes). The same is true for any classes that you can't modify the definition of.

Comment: @mgiuca Sorry, you both are correct. Removing my comment and +1 from me.

Comment: Sounds like its similar to how python handles it (according to mgiuca). Interesting.

Comment: @B T Yes, except with two important differences: a) C++ does not have the reverse versions that Python has, and b) C++ does allow you to define an operator overload function outside of the class, which means you can augment the behaviour of operators for a particular type even if you don't have write access to the class.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that given `X + Y`, the compiler should look for both `X.op_plus(Y)` and `Y.op_added_to(X)`; each implementation should include an attribute indicating whether it should be a 'preferred', 'normal', 'fallback' implementation, and optionally also indicating that it is "common".  If both implementations are defined, and they implementations are of different priorities (e.g. "preferred" and "normal"), use the type to select a preference.  If both are defined to be of the same priority, and both are "common", favor the `X.op_plus(Y)` form.  If both are defined with the same priority and they are not both "common", flag an error.

I would suggest that the ability to prioritize overloads and conversions would IMHO a very important feature for a language to have.  It is not helpful for languages to squawk about ambiguous overloads in cases where both candidates would do the same thing, but languages should squawk in cases where two possible overloads would have different meanings, each of which would be useful in certain contexts.  For example, given `someFloat==someDouble` or `someDouble==someLong`, a compiler *should* squawk, since there can be usefulness to knowing whether the numerical quantities represented by two values match, and there can also be usefulness in knowing whether the left-hand operand holds the best possible representation (for its type) of the value in the right-hand operand.  Java and C# do not flag ambiguity in either case, opting instead to use the first meaning for the first expression and the second for the second, even though either meaning might be useful in either case.  I would suggest that it would be better to reject such comparisons than to have them implement inconsistent semantics.

Overall, I'd suggest as a philosophy that a good language design should let a programmer indicate what's important and what isn't.  If a programmer knows that certain "ambiguities" aren't problems, but other ones are, it should be easy to have the compiler flag the latter but not the former.

*Addendum*

I looked briefly through your proposal; it sees you're expecting bindings to be fully dynamic.  I've worked with a language like that (HyperTalk, circa 1988) and it was "interesting".  Consider, for example, that "2X" < "3" < 4 < 10 < "11" < "2X".  Double dispatch can sometimes be useful, but only in cases where operators overloads with different semantics (e.g. string and numeric comparisons) are limited to operating on disjoint sets of things.  Forbidding ambiguous operations at compile time is a good thing, since the programmer will be in a position to specify what's intended.  Having such ambiguity trigger a run-time error is a bad thing, because the programmer may be long gone by the time an error surfaces.  Consequently, I really can't offer any advice for how to do run-time double dispatch for operators except to say "don't", unless at compile time you restrict the operands to combinations where any possible overload would always have the same semantics.

For example, if you had an abstract "immutable list of numbers" type, with a member to report the length or return the number at a particular index, you could specify that two instances are equal if they have the same length, and every for every index they return the same number.  While it would be possible to compare any two instances for equality by examining every item, that could be inefficient if e.g. one instance was a "BunchOfZeroes" type which simply held an integer N=1000000 and didn't actually store any items, and the other was an "NCopiesOfArray" which held N=500000 and {0,0} as the array to be copied.  If many instances of those types are going to be compared, efficiency could be improved by having such comparisons invoke a method which, after checking overall array length, checks whether the "template" array contains any non-zero elements.  If it doesn't, then it can be reported as equal the bunch-of-zeroes array without having to perform 1,000,000 element comparisons.  Note that the invocation of such a method by double dispatch would not alter the program's behavior--it would merely allow it to execute more quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but having all those conditions to consider is a ton of cognitive overhead, and thus would make the system much harder to reason about. I agree with you that the compiler shouldn't complain if both of the options in an ambiguous situation do the same thing. I think the compiler should be able to figure that out tho, and not rely on the programmer telling it to trust them that they're the same (that can cause problems when the programmer is wrong about that). Lima does allow you to choose which to use - calling operators as functions: `meta[obj1].operator[+][obj1 obj2]`

Comment: @BT: It will not be possible in general for a compiler to know whether two methods do the same thing unless something tells it that.  As for cognitive load, a certain amount of complexity is always going to be necessary "someplace"; attempting to over-simplify one part of a design will generally result in extra complexity or "surprising behaviors" elsewhere.  For example, how many people would expect that in Java, `Math.Round(2147483646L)` will yield 2147483647?  Such behavior is a consequence of Java's "ranking" primitives, rather than using more detailed rules for type conversions.

Comment: I disagree that it isn't possible. Difficult yes, impossible no. In any case the programmer can know if two functions are the same, the compiler should be able to know. However, even if the compiler doesn't know if two functions are the same or not, the downside is just an error and the programmer having to specify which object's operator to use. I also don't agree that simplifying one area necessarily leads to surprising behaviors elsewhere. Complexity isn't a zero-sum game. That is where the art of language design comes in. But please feel free to give my language a scathing critique ; )

Comment: @BT: A good language design will identify surprising or annoying behaviors, and try to figure out the minimal amount of complexity necessary to mitigate them.  Further, I subscribe to the philosophy that many efforts spent on having computers *infer* what people want could be better spent on making it easier for people to *specify* what they want *with minimal repetition*.  Further, one should try to have things which are *semantically* different use different syntax even if they happen to generate the same code.  One of my pet peeves with Java/.NET floating-point rules is that...

Comment: ...a statement like `someVariable = (float)Math.Sin(otherVariable);` could mean "I want to store the computation as accurately as possible in `someVariable`, which I believe is `float`", or "I know `someVariable` is a `double`, but I want to force the value to be rounded to `float` precision".  The run-time effect of the cast is the same in either case, but using the same syntax for both will make it harder to rework the code if it's necessary to change `someVariable` to use higher precision.

Comment: I agree with a lot of that. In fact, the primary selling point of Lima is that it gives the programmer the ability to specify exactly what they mean and what they want. For example, you can tell the program the range of external inputs you expect, with what probabilities. This allows for a ton more accurate *inferring*. Lima also has the ability to specify the (in)accuracy of numeric calculations so the compiler can optimize things like that. Thanks for the help. And I really *would* appreciate feedback on the language as I've spec'd it if you'd be willing.